# How to get Mint Address of of SPL token using associated token account?

Tags: spl-token, associated-token-account, mint

I want to know if there is any way I can find out mint-address of spl-token if I using associated token-account of any one of the holders

Something like this:

```
const mintAddress = getMintAddress(tokenAccountAddress)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import {getAccount} from "@solana/spl-token"

const tokenAccount = await getAccount(connection, tokenAccountAddress)

console.log(tokenAccount.mint.toBase58())
```

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#getAccount

Here is a list of properties for a token account:

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/interfaces/Account.html