# Token Transfer instruction in transaction not returning SPL token

Tags: spl-token, transactions, transfer, instructions

When parsing some transactions for the token transfers instructions, I noticed some token transfer instruction does not include the actual token mint, but has an amount, what are the possible reasons for that and if I do want to know the token mint involved with that transfer how do I go about it?

Providing some examples (these transactions are all quite similar and look to all be interacting with the LuLoQt7G3ZN1mCCB2fBcVcxKgBSs5WMXzYgws2qSfWH program):

instruction #6 Token Program: Transfer:
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2eHXy5sabYN4qWZQGrbNaggT4gz8Cn7pgbR1N2jQbV8CAtEfHZ9qbqM48kL8mEHufUnCvpfq7cgRodYAjWMzHQE7

instruction #6 Token Program: Transfer:
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/33oKTMTBw31i81rQwnc3dZ95ZhKuysRw7xFr7cnPCYtfBv8ijbtQ3QM6EgBb2HRRo9usR5T8X6xYbZBCtYzHrZmG

instruction #6 Token Program: Transfer:
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2j67p3LzHRLRp3fY5EX9cay8WXkMPH9UyZ49HzARY68Tf7BM7cfru8AvCGQDRJkxvEbr3hefgbNg7K8uYaHst1Yc

Answer (score 2):

if i understood properly your question the reason is that you don't need to include the token mint in the transfer instruction. The source & destination token account are enough, because anyway these account are token account so they are created to "work" with the token mint. So i guess the mint address of the transfered token is implicit.

Comment: hey, sorry if the question was unclear, will update it to clarify. Your answer does make sense in addressing the reason why token mint isn't explicitly included. I'm guessing to know the token mint, we would have to do something like [this](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3838/how-to-get-mint-address-of-of-spl-token-using-associated-token-account) from the token accounts